# Display a sin(x) wave in java console

Tags: java, math

My question is about display a sin(x) wave, but *transform* it vertically 90 degrees to the Y axis

[image]

```
int num = 7;
for (double y = 2; y >= 0; y-=0.2) {
  for (double x = 0; x <= num; x+=0.2) {
    if ( ((0.1+x) >= Math.asin((double)y-1)) && (((double)x-0.1) <= Math.asin((double)y-1)) )
      System.out.print('*');
    else
      System.out.print(' ');
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. What are you trying to do and what is the expected output?

Comment: simply flip the x and y values of the normal sin for plotting? I doubt there is some function that gives you unlimited solutions  for x between -PI and PI that would correspond to a height in y...

Comment: https://gitlab.com/kocsispeter/SinX-to-Console/blob/dbb9115f01a02698bb7b56c14cdf6de18ca2d3a1/sin(x).jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (double x = 0; x <= Math.PI; x += 0.15) {
            int sinValue = (int) Math.round(Math.sin(x) * 30);
            for (int j = 0; j < sinValue; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to create an array of characters corresponding to the output display. Fill up the array with asterisks as appropriate; you can iterate over X or over Y, whatever is easier, you aren't constrained as you are when you output directly to the console. Depending on how your code is organized, you might fill the array and then transpose it (i.e., swap the (i, j) element with (j, i) element). Finally, print out your array element by element.

Comment: It is doable without a 2D array, if edge cases of `asin` are properly handled. But a 1D array would help by reducing the number of calls to `print`

Comment: Well, working with a 2d array (essentially a display image) is simpler and more general. It's easy enough to work with the inverse of sine, but many common functions don't have any simple inverse, even allowing for multiple inverse values (preimages, to be exact). It can be done but it's not clear to me that the benefit outweighs the trouble of doing it that way, unless there is a hard constraint which really requires that approach.

Comment: Thanks Guys, finally i found the solution fot this using for loops: